# Eclipse error adding images to an array

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

I am new to android programming.
I found a tutorial on how to create a simple gallery app for android phones/tablets. I finished a beta of the app, which was using 10 example images called **a1.png, a2.png... a10.png** in a new resource folder *(App/res/drawable/)*

My code was:

```
private Integer[] SmallPrev = { R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2... R.drawable.a10 };
```

and it was working as it should when i tested the app on my phone.
I saw that **a1, a2... a10** are indentified somehow in the **R.java** file in my project:

```
 public static final class drawable {
    public static final int a1=0x7f020000;
    public static final int a10=0x7f020001;
    public static final int a2=0x7f020002;
    public static final int a3=0x7f020003;
    public static final int a4=0x7f020004;
    public static final int a5=0x7f020005;
    public static final int a6=0x7f020006;
    public static final int a7=0x7f020007;
    public static final int a8=0x7f020008;
    public static final int a9=0x7f020009;
```

So far, so good...
But today I tried to make a new version of the App, using the original amount of images - 130 (maybe more in the future)

I used a simple program to print the code as text, and the result was:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Integer[] SmallPrev = { R.drawable.av64pxprev1,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev2, R.drawable.av64pxprev3, R.drawable.av64pxprev4,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev5, R.drawable.av64pxprev6, R.drawable.av64pxprev7,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev8, R.drawable.av64pxprev9, R.drawable.av64pxprev10,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev11, R.drawable.av64pxprev12, R.drawable.av64pxprev13,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev14, R.drawable.av64pxprev15, R.drawable.av64pxprev16,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev17, R.drawable.av64pxprev18, R.drawable.av64pxprev19,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev20, R.drawable.av64pxprev21, R.drawable.av64pxprev22,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev23, R.drawable.av64pxprev24, R.drawable.av64pxprev25,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev26, R.drawable.av64pxprev27, R.drawable.av64pxprev28,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev29, R.drawable.av64pxprev30, R.drawable.av64pxprev31,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev32, R.drawable.av64pxprev33, R.drawable.av64pxprev34,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev35, R.drawable.av64pxprev36, R.drawable.av64pxprev37,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev38, R.drawable.av64pxprev39, R.drawable.av64pxprev40,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev41, R.drawable.av64pxprev42, R.drawable.av64pxprev43,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev44, R.drawable.av64pxprev45, R.drawable.av64pxprev46,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev47, R.drawable.av64pxprev48, R.drawable.av64pxprev49,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev50, R.drawable.av64pxprev51, R.drawable.av64pxprev52,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev53, R.drawable.av64pxprev54, R.drawable.av64pxprev55,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev56, R.drawable.av64pxprev57, R.drawable.av64pxprev58,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev59, R.drawable.av64pxprev60, R.drawable.av64pxprev61,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev62, R.drawable.av64pxprev63, R.drawable.av64pxprev64,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev65, R.drawable.av64pxprev66, R.drawable.av64pxprev67,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev68, R.drawable.av64pxprev69, R.drawable.av64pxprev70,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev71, R.drawable.av64pxprev72, R.drawable.av64pxprev73,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev74, R.drawable.av64pxprev75, R.drawable.av64pxprev76,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev77, R.drawable.av64pxprev78, R.drawable.av64pxprev79,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev80, R.drawable.av64pxprev81, R.drawable.av64pxprev82,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev83, R.drawable.av64pxprev84, R.drawable.av64pxprev85,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev86, R.drawable.av64pxprev87, R.drawable.av64pxprev88,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev89, R.drawable.av64pxprev90, R.drawable.av64pxprev91,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev92, R.drawable.av64pxprev93, R.drawable.av64pxprev94,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev95, R.drawable.av64pxprev96, R.drawable.av64pxprev97,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev98, R.drawable.av64pxprev99, R.drawable.av64pxprev100,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev101, R.drawable.av64pxprev102, R.drawable.av64pxprev103,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev104, R.drawable.av64pxprev105, R.drawable.av64pxprev106,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev107, R.drawable.av64pxprev108, R.drawable.av64pxprev109,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev110, R.drawable.av64pxprev111, R.drawable.av64pxprev112,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev113, R.drawable.av64pxprev114, R.drawable.av64pxprev115,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev116, R.drawable.av64pxprev117, R.drawable.av64pxprev118,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev119, R.drawable.av64pxprev120, R.drawable.av64pxprev121,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev122, R.drawable.av64pxprev123, R.drawable.av64pxprev124,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev125, R.drawable.av64pxprev126, R.drawable.av64pxprev127,
        R.drawable.av64pxprev128, R.drawable.av64pxprev129, R.drawable.av64pxprev130 };
```

But now all the file names have **errors** *(_filename_ cannot be resolved or is not a field)*, although the only thing I did was to replace the **a1, a2.... a10** files with **av64pxprev1, av64pxprev2... av64pxprev130**, all with **.png** extension.

When I checked the **R.java** file I found that nothing has changed:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int a1=0x7f020000;
    public static final int a10=0x7f020001;
    public static final int a2=0x7f020002;
    public static final int a3=0x7f020003;
    public static final int a4=0x7f020004;
    public static final int a5=0x7f020005;
    public static final int a6=0x7f020006;
    public static final int a7=0x7f020007;
    public static final int a8=0x7f020008;
    public static final int a9=0x7f020009;
```

I have tried many ways of adding the images as a resource, but none of them worked (restarting Eclipse too), leaving all the new files **NOT** indentified in the **R.java** file, but all the old ones unmodified, although I removed them.

***Can anyone explain me why is that and how can I fix it or indentify the files myself?***

Comment: Try a Project/Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: try take `int`...[link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohit008/GridView-Bitmap-Cache/master/src/com/example/Images.java)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Tried it, the R.java file disappeared and still got the same error

Comment: @Mohit It does not work either, maybe there is something wrong with Eclipse on my computer

Comment: No, it's not Eclipse, nor your computer. Google for `android r.java not generated`

Comment: Yes: follow my advice - Google those words.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I got the solution for the R.java, but still got errors, although all images now have declarations                                                                                  `public static final int av64pxprev1=0x7f020057;`

Comment: Project/Clean, Rebuild

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thank you for your time, finally got it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer to my question:

1. Clean/Rebuild until the R.java file has the image definitions you need
2. Delete `import android.R;` from my **MainActivity.java** file

Those 2 steps seem to fix the problem.